# Wrapper for printf

Tags: c, arduino

I am coding under Arduino and I would like to develop serial print formatting function, so I am trying to use `sprintf` of unknown sized buffer. Basically, we can avoid talking about Arduino and its serial output and consider writing text to a buffer and then printing it by using `printf`. I've tried this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void printf0( const char* format, ... ) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(format, args);
    va_end( args );
}

void printf1(const char* format,...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  char buf[vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, args)];
  sprintf(buf, format, args);
  printf(buf);
  va_end(args);
}

int main()
{
    printf0("Hello, %d!\n", 15);
    printf1("Hello, %d!\n", 15);
    return 0;
}
```

`printf0` function is an accurate example I found [here](http://www.ozzu.com/cpp-tutorials/tutorial-writing-custom-printf-wrapper-function-t89166.html). My tries is function `printf1`, which produces unpredictable number. Example output of the above programme is:

```
Hello, 15!
Hello, 860799736!
```

Comment: `sprintf(buf, format, args);` should be `vsnprintf(buf, sizeof buf, format, args);`.

Comment: @LPs calling `vsnprintf` with a `NULL` pointer and size `0` will only return the number of `char`s the function would write to a buffer.

Comment: @Jarod42 - A doubt the question is about C++ at all. Seems to be the usual "double tag" spam.

Comment: @mch Well, I learned something today ;) Thx. BTW he/she should add at least +1 to that returned value for null terminator.

Comment: Do not edit your question with suggested solution. Otherwise other users will not be able to understand answers!

Comment: @LPs actually my mistake regarding missing ' + 1' didn't imply working of this code propriety and my change didn't impacted this code to start working

Comment: No, it is a big problem. It is UB access an array out of bounds

Comment: @LPs but this is still not the reason of behavior I was asking about

Comment: Even `char buf[1 + vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, args)];` is dangerous. What happens if the caller passes something too big for the stack? Worse, what happens if `vsnprintf()` encounters and error and returns a negative value?  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vfprintf.html (and the referenced http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vfprintf.html for return values)  Better to check the return value before defining and allocating the array.

Comment: ...but would be the next problem for a next question...

Comment: Does Arduino even support VLAs? I thought it was some C++:ish dialect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`args` is a `va_list`, so you cannot call `sprintf` with it. You have to use `vsprintf` or `vsnprintf`:

```
sprintf(buf, format, args);
```

should be

```
vsnprintf(buf, sizeof buf, format, args);
```

Also you should add 1 to the size of `buf` for the 0-terminator of the string:

```
char buf[vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, args) + 1];
```

<strike>It seems that the first call to `vsnprintf` changes `args`, so you have to add</strike>

```
va_end(args);
va_start(args, format);
```

between the 2 calls:
http://ideone.com/5YI4Or

It seems that the first call to `vsnprintf` changes `args`, but you should not call `va_start` twice. You should use `va_copy` instead, so add

```
va_list args2;
va_copy(args2, args);
```

after initializing `args`. Also do not forget to call `va_end(args2);` too:

http://ideone.com/loTRNL

Link to the `va_copy` man page: https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_copy

Comment: It doesn't work on my platform: I suspect that args is modified by `vsnprintf`  so second `vsnprintf` fails.

Comment: yup, good point for your remark as for adding one to the buffer size. your solution will be checked

Comment: snippet provided at the end of your answer checked. this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: Rather than doing `va_start` twice, you should make `va_copy` of it instead. Standard specifically says *"The va_start macro shall be invoked before any access to the unnamed arguments."*

Comment: @user694733 [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vfprintf.html) also states:  *As these functions invoke the `va_arg` macro, the value of `ap` after the return is unspecified.* That's *why* the second call of `vsnprintf()` needs another copy of the variable arguments.