# C++ _snprintf returns -1

Tags: c++, printf

I have a strange problem with _snprintf function,
code:

```
char string1[] = "string";
char string2[] = "Description";
char string3[] = "BIOS Date: 05/12/15 15:30:43 Ver: 04.06.05";
char *buffer = new char[64];
int resx = _snprintf(buffer, 64, "[%03u] %s %s = (%s)", 16, string1, string2, string3);
```

For me it returns -1, but why?
In documentation said that -1 return when encoding error occurred, but I'm not encoding anything, there's no unicode formatting?
I just need length value to expand buffer with

I also tried a _snprintf_s it causes assertion, but must return a needen length

Also I can't take enough big buffer, because string1,string2,string3 can be any strings in real situation

Thank you

EDIT:
Final solution that working for me in Visual Studio 2013 and 2015
EDIT2:
Fixed usage of va_list (thank you to mch)

```
string format(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    string result;

    va_list vl1, vl2;
    va_start(vl1, fmt);
    va_copy(vl2, vl1);

    int needen_size = _vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, fmt, vl1);
    if (needen_size > 0)
    {
        if (char *buffer = new char[needen_size + 1]) {
            _vsnprintf(buffer, needen_size, fmt, vl2);
            buffer[needen_size] = '\0';
            result.assign(buffer);
            delete[] buffer;
        }
    }

    va_end(vl1);
    va_end(vl2);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the resulting string > 64 characters in length?

Comment: Yes, but I need to know how much to allocate to fit all the content
In documentation written that result value must be needen length, but it returns -1 like error happened

Comment: On what platform do you use `_snprintf` vs `snprintf` (note the underscore)?

Comment: [`snprintf` returns 71 for me](http://ideone.com/LGVfmo). It seems `_snprintf` is MS specific, the difference to `snprinft` that it does not append a `'\0'` if the string does not fit, but should still return the number of characters needed...

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: Using of sprintf_s instead of _snprintf causing assertion: Buffer too small
But how can I know allocation size?
I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: just checked with Visual Studio 2015: `snprintf` returns 71 both when passing a buffer which is too small and when passing a nullptr, `_snprint` returns -1 when the buffer is too small, and 71 when passing a nullptr

Comment: The first `vsnprintf` call uses your `vl`, you are not allowed to use it again in the next call. Take a look at my answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42131941/3684343

Comment: Thank you, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass zero for the size and NULL for the pointer it returns what you must allocate / buffer size:

```
char string1[] = "string";
char string2[] = "Description";
char string3[] = "BIOS Date: 05/12/15 15:30:43 Ver: 04.06.05";

resx = _snprintf(NULL, 0, "[%03u] %s %s = (%s)", 16, string1, string2, string3);
```

Then call again with correct size

```
char *buffer = new char[resx+1];

int resx = _snprintf(buffer, resx, "[%03u] %s %s = (%s)", 16, string1, string2, string3);
```

Comment: In contrast to the behavior standardized in C99, `_snprintf()` only returns the required size in case `buffer` is a null pointer. The conforming `snprintf()` appears to be available in VS 2015. Interestingly the definitions of the return values appear to change through the available versions... Note that `snprintf` is not equal to `_snprintf`.

Comment: Thank you! It's working, final solution in first post